# Drive v3 API files method gives "invalid parameter" error when used with corpora=domain

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I need to access all files of an organisation in TeamDrives via a server-to-server app. All users that have access to the files have emails username@organisation-domain.

I created a service account and see it listed in the Google Console (Oganisation -> Project -> IAM Admin -> IAM) together with the currently logged user (username@organisation-domain) that has the admin role and the full access to the files in TeamDrives.

[image: Google Console]

Via this service account I make request *"/drive/v3/files?corpora=domain"* which returns:

```
"domain": "global",
"reason": "invalid",
"message": "Invalid Value",
"locationType": "parameter",
"location": "q"
```

though there's no "q"-parameter.

If I remove "corpora=domain" part, I get all files that belong the service account.

I tried to add any q-parameter just to try, e.g. *"q=name+contains+'text'"*. Without corpora everything is ok - I get the filtered files (belonging the service account of course). If I add corpora=domain, I get the same error about invalid parameter.

I tried corpus=domain, corpora=DOMAIN etc. from other answers, no result.  corpus=domain and corpus=DOMAIN give the same error. corpora=DOMAIN and corpora=default give "Invalid Value" error (without location).

No matter what I try I just keep getting this strange error - invalid value in the q even if there's no q-parameter.

I tried also

```
corpora: "teamDrive",
includeTeamDriveItems: true,
supportsTeamDrives: true,
teamDriveId: 'XXX',
```

The service account (via email name@id.iam.gserviceaccount.com) has been added to the members of the TeamDrive ID in the request, but I get:

```
"domain": "global",
"reason": "teamDriveMembershipRequired",
"message": "The attempted action requires Team Drive membership."
```

Any ideas what do I do wrong?